# Undefined method `group' for [2, 7, 0, 0]:Array [Chartkick]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

I am trying to create a chart for a Pack database, in which the x axis will be each day, and the y axis will be a count of the `:amount` field in the Pack database. I am currently using the following code:

```
= line_chart @packs.pluck("amount").group(:created_at).count
```

I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `group' for [2, 7, 0, 0]:Array
```

How do I display a chart using Chartkick, in which it counts or shows the :amount record for that day?

Comment: Try giving it like this `-@packs.each do |pack|` after that  `= line_chart pack.pluck("amount").group(:created_at).count`

Comment: try reversing the order of the calls: `@packs.group(:created_at).pluck("amount").count`

Comment: Reversing it ended up displaying an integer and not the graph.

Comment: @Pavan, your solution created an error saying no method 'pluck'

Answer (score 2):

```
= line_chart @packs.group(:created_at).count('amount')
```

or

```
= line_chart @packs.group(:created_at).sum('amount')
```